# How can virtualenv access external non-Python libraries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I'm using Python 2.7 with virtualenv (on Mac), and installing the python package "scrypt" (`pip install scrypt`) - which requires OpenSSL to be installed, so that the OpenSSL C++ header/implementation files can be appropriately included on compilation.

While a global 'pip install' finds and compiles the appropriate C++ header files for OpenSSL (which is installed with Homebrew), I can't install it using when the virtualenv is active. I get a file not found for the OpenSSL header files:

```
fatal error: 'openssl/aes.h' file not found
```

I've already tried creating the virtualenv with the `--system-site-packages` option (as "scrypt" was installed in the "site-packages" directory of the system python) - but this doesn't seem to use the system scrypt. I also added the OpenSSL library folder using add2virtualenv, without any luck.

Are there any other approaches one can try to let programs in the virtualenv find non-Python system packages/libraries?